# Angular ui.router anchor tags issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a newbie to angularjs. I have created a nested view using the angular UI router. The Problem I am facing here is anchor tags are not clickable. I could not Figure out the Problem. Any Help is appreciated.

**folder structure:**-

```
AngularUiRouterProject
|-controllers
   |-child_one.js     /*Child_one Controller*/
   |-child_two.js     /*Child_two Controller*/
   |-page_one.js      /*Page_one Controller*/
   |-page_two.js      /*Page_two Controller*/
|-templates
   |-page_one.html    /*Parent One Template*
   |-page_two.html    /*Parent_two Template*/
   |-child_one.html   /*Child_one Template*/
   |-child_two.html   /*Child_Two Template*/
|-app.js              /*Angular Module File*/
|-config.js           /*Ui Router Config File*/
|-index.html          /*Main Page*/
```

Here is the Plunker Link [AngularUiRouterProject](https://plnkr.co/edit/hpySPddl7Gim4kX03XOL?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ui-sref` takes the `state` as the value and not the `url`. Remove the `\` from the `ui-sref` which then becomes the state name

[Working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/V4IJSC1LtPQcMVvsdDg6?p=preview)

Note that for the plunker to work, i had to remove directory name `templates` for the routing to work from `templateUrl:"templates\page_two.html",` You can modify it as per your convience.